# Android studio application notification permission off by default?

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, android-permissions, onesignal

I'm debugging my app and preparing to launch it.
I'm using Onesignal to send notifications, and everything works fine. I send notifications using the Onesignal custom category.

When I send a notification it arrives, but making any sound or vibration or showing up sliding from the top (like WhatsApp or Fb notification).

Notification image
[image]

The problem seems is when the app is installed by default some of the notification permissions come disabled like sound and floating notifications:

Permission image
[image]

Any ideas? Do I need to use any "manifest" permission to enable those settings by default?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you solve it?